# Why are holding patterns clockwise by default?

Tags: holding, precision-approach

PANS-OPS (Doc 8168), Procedures for Air Navigation Services, volume 2, section 4, chapter 1: "If no operational considerations prevail, right turns holding patterns should be established."

When was this convention established, and why?

Comment: Interesting question - especially given the fact that airport patterns use left-hand patterns.

Comment: @Pondlife unfortunately not. No references, and the explanation does not make sense: a left hand circuit puts an aircraft on the other side of the runway from the right hand hold, assuming they are landing in the same direction!

Comment: The link was interesting though https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2017/may/01/ifr-fix-what-were-they-thinking

Comment: I'm happy with the standard explanation of why circuits are to the left: aircraft overtake on the right, just like ships, so the pilot sits on the left, just like cars in countries which drive on the right, so it makes sense for the aircraft circuit to be to the left so the pilot can keep sight of the runway.

Comment: I understand that the other question may not have a good answer yet, however this does seem to be exactly the same question. The way StackExchange works is that we try to avoid duplicates. In this situation, the best thing is usually to upvote the existing question, which draws attention to it and gives people more incentive to find a good answer. The [tour] might be useful to explain more about how the site works.

Comment: @JamesJames - “a left hand circuit puts an aircraft on the other side of the runway from the right hand hold, assuming they are landing in the same direction!” This is true of a Hold in lieu of a Procedure Turn to reverse course. A right hand turn hold after a Missed Approach would put the aircraft on the same side of the extended center line as a left traffic pattern. This would facilitate a return to the airfield for a circling approach. It would also give the left seat PIC a clear line of sight to the outside of the holding pattern (except when banking).

Comment: AOPA also has a few good possible explanations. These include the fact that a right hand hold above the airport separates aircraft from the fixed wing aircraft in a left traffic pattern. Similar to rotary-wing traffic patterns. And, right hand holds near the extended centerline would provide some separation for departing aircraft who would attempt to pass on their right when encountering an approaching aircraft.